# How can I delete an SSIS Package saved on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I have an SSIS package that I've saved under Maintenance Plans on SQL Server 2005. Though I can select SSIS packages, I am not sure how I can delete them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to delete the package from Database Engine --> Management --> Maintenance Plans. Try connecting to "Integration Services" instead of the Database engine and look for the package you want to delete under Running Packages or Stored Packages.

From there you should be able to right click and delete.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for a scripted method to remove the packages from SQL Server you can do the following:

The following code will delete a package deployed as "\Maintenance Plans\DatabaseBackup-Full-All" from a server named "MYSQLSERVER01"

```
DTUTIL /SQL "\Maintenance Plans\DatabaseBackup-Full-All" /DELETE /SourceServer MYSQLSERVER01 >> rollback.log
```

The following code will deploy a package located in the current directory on the filesystem named "DatabaseBackup-Full-All.dtsx" to a server named "MYSQLSERVER01" as "\Maintenance Plans\DatabaseBackup-Full-All"

```
DTUTIL /FILE "DatabaseBackup-Full-All.dtsx" /COPY SQL;"\Maintenance Plans\DatabaseBackup-Full-All" /QUIET /DestServer MYSQLSERVER01 >> release.log
```

These code samples are run from the command line.
I have also included the >> release.log and >> rollback.log so that you can save the execution log to a file.

Don't forget to cd into whatever directory has you Package File to run the script as is, or update the code above to have the complete (local or unc) file path of your package.

Comment: Using DTUTIL from the commandline also works for a slightly different setup with SQL Server v.12 and not being able to connect to Integration services from within SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: +1 I had over 200 packages to delete and this is the command I needed.  Adding the script I used to generate your suggested command.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly what I needed since I could not connect to "Integration Services".

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what version of SQL Server you are using, there is a system table that contains the packages.  In my 2005 version the table is called msdb.dbo.sysdtspackages90.  You can also look for tables such as msdb.dbo.sysdtspackages or msdb.dbo.sysssispackages.  To delete a package simply delete it from this table.

Answer (score 1):

John DaCosta's solution worked for me.  I wrote the following query to output the deletion commands and pasted the results into a command shell window:

```
SELECT CONCAT('DTUTIL /SQL "\', f.foldername, '\', name, '" /DELETE /SourceServer MyServerName')
FROM msdb.dbo.sysssispackages s
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysssispackagefolders f
    on s.folderid = f.folderid
WHERE ownersid <> 0x01
```